# How to add more items to a static list in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-developer-api

How can I add more elements to the static list in the jetpack compose

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable 
fun AddNotesToList(notesList: List<String>) { 
    val listState = rememberScrollState() 
    Log.d("TAG", notesList.toString()) 
    LazyColumn() { 
        items(notesList.size) { 
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center, 
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 15.dp, top = 15.dp, bottom = 1.dp, end = 15.dp)
                    .fillMaxSize() .horizontalScroll(listState)
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)) .padding(15.dp)
                    .animateItemPlacement(animationSpec = tween(1000))) { 
                        Text(text = notesList[it], 
                            color = Color.Black, 
                            modifier = Modifier.align( Alignment.BottomCenter)
                                .animateItemPlacement(animationSpec = tween(10000)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my addition to the Ui function, this is now I add elements

```
AddNotesToList(notesList = listOf(
    "Drink water", 
    "Read Books", 
    "Eat fruits", 
    "Go for a Walk", 
    "Drink water", 
    "Read Books", 
    "Eat fruits", 
    "Go for## Heading ## a Walk", 
    "Go for a Walk", 
    "Drink water", 
    "Read Books", 
    "Eat fruits", 
    "Go for a Walk"))
```

now I want to add one more element and I am trying this
function

```
@Composable 
fun AddNewNote(noteDescription: String) {
    Log.d("noteDescription", noteDescription) 
    AddNotesToList(notesList = listOf(noteDescription))
}
```

Comment: U did not add new element, U just replaced the whole list with the list of one element

Comment: @jorieitomuke Can you please suggest me how to do it ? I am new to jetpack and i cant figure it out .

Comment: Do you know how to use viewModel and `collectAsState()`? if not, I'll write you an answer down below.

Comment: No @jorieitomuke I dont know. Is it possible without viewmodels ?

Comment: It's possible but any changes to the list will be lost.

Comment: It is possible without using VM too 
 AddNewNote { item ->
                //updating state with added item
                noteListState = noteListState + listOf(item)
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
val _noteList = remember { MutableStateFlow(listOf<String>()) }
val noteList by remember { _noteList }.collectAsState()

// Add note
fun addItem(item: String) {
    val newList = ArrayList(noteList)
    newList.add(yourItem)
    _noteList.value = newList
}
```

And then you can pass `noteList` to your `LazyColumn`

Answer (score 0):

```
   This is how i call my function 
AddNewNote { item -> //updating state with added item noteListState = noteListState + listOf(item) } 




 This is my function 
    
    @OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun AddNewNote(onNewNoteAdded: (String) -> Unit) {
        val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        val (visible) = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = visible,
            enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { 9000 * it }),
            exit = fadeOut()
        ) {
            if (openDialog.value) {
                AlertDialog(
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        openDialog.value = false
                    },
                    title = {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier.animateEnterExit(
                                enter = slideInVertically(
                                    initialOffsetY = { 9000 * it },
                                ),
                                exit = slideOutVertically()
                            ),
    
                            text = "Add Note Description"
    
    
                        )
                    },
                    text = {
                        Column() {
                            TextField(
                                value = text,
                                onValueChange = { text = it }
                            )
                            Text("Note description")
                        }
                    },
                    buttons = {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(all = 8.dp),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                        ) {
                            val addNoteButtonState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
                            if (addNoteButtonState) {
                                onNewNoteAdded(text)
                            } else {
                                Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                                    Button(
                                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                                        onClick = {
                                            if (text != "") {
                                                onNewNoteAdded(text)
                                            }
                                            //  addNoteButtonState = true
    
                                            openDialog.value = false
                                        }
                                    ) {
                                        Text(
                                            "Add Note To The List",
                                            )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
    
                    )
            }
        }
    
    
    }
```